# Disable CSRF Protection from particular URL - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am doing one 3rd party payment gateway to my Laravel 5.5 web application.And after a payment has been declined, page is then redirected to the cancel page..

```
http://example.com/paymentcancel
```

And I update one value here after cancel. When I update, it gives one error

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php

my route is

```
   Route::post('paymentcancel', 'RoomsController@cancelorder');
```

my verifycsrftoken.php..

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as
BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier {
    /**
    * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $except = [
        'paymentcancel/*',
    ];
}
```

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-disable-csrf-middleware-on-certain-routes

Comment: It probably is the `/*`in this case, because there is no slash in the request made

Comment: @ThomasMoors thanks ..working..